# Scala: Implicit Value lookup with Type Class idiom

Tags: scala, reflection

I am attempting to extend the idea of using value classes for type safety as described here http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html to a more abstract version that allows implicit conversions. For example, I have some Measure trait

```
trait Measure {
implicit def +[B <: Measure](other: B): Measure
val value: Double
}
```

and some implementations

```
//this will compile because [_ , Meters] is not ambiguous since
//for this example im only using one conversion. see below


case class Meters(value: Double) extends Measure {
   def +[B <: Measure](other: B): Meters = Meters(other.value * implicitly[Converter[_ , Meters]].factor + this.value) }
case class Fathoms(value: Double) extends Measure {
   def +[B <: Measure](other: B): Fathoms = Fathoms(other.value * implicitly[Converter[_ , Fathoms]].factor + this.value) }
```

and a converter trait and implementation for the implicit lookup mechanism to find

```
trait Converter[F, T]{
  val factor: Double
}
implicit object Meter2Fathom extends Converter[Meter, Fathom]{
  val factor: Double = .556
}
implicit object Fathom2Meter extends Converter[Fathom, Meter]{
  val factor: Double = 1.8
}
```

Is there a way to define Converter implementations on "whatever B is"? I want run time error if we try to add together two measures for which there doesnt exist a conversion factor, but still be able to compile.

```
//will not compile of course. the idea is to somehow reify whatever B 
// is and look that implicit converter up, instead of actual B.
case class Meters(value: Double) extends Measure {
  def +[B <: Measure](other: B): Meters = Meters(this.value + other.value * implicitly[Converter[* B *, Meters]].factor
```

Comment: General design solution for these type of problems is to assume one representation of `Measure` to be standard.. lets say `Meter`. And all... other Measure will implement a `toStandard` or `toMeter` and `fromStandard` or `fromMeter` function. Now do all... calculations in `Meter`... then convert to that `Mesure` by using `fromMeter`.

Comment: Other more functionally pure but advanced method can be to use `adhoc-polymorphism` with Type-classes... a very good read on Type-classes -> http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html

Comment: This is probably the way to go. one more computation step in the conversion alleviates need of having n^2 conversion factors. +1

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood what you want is magnet pattern. There is an extensive blog here: http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/